# Три кирпича на flex

Tags: css3, flexbox

Помогите пожалуйста сверстать [такой](http://i.yapx.ru/CvRL.png) блок. Для меня проблема выставить блокам соответствующую высоту.

Хотелось бы ипользовать только возможности flexbox и не добавлять в html новые контейнеры.

Моя попытка [тут](https://jsfiddle.net/gd5aq2gx/1/)

html:

```
<div class="timer-button">
    <div class="title">Сегодня у нас</div>

    <div class="col col_days">
        <span class="value ng-binding">15</span>
        <span class="label">апреля</span>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col col_hours">
        <span class="value ng-binding">18</span>
        <span class="label">часов</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
body{
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.timer-button {
    width: 90%;
    min-height: 50%;
    background: #e15d29;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

    .timer-button .title{
        background: lime;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40%;
    }


        .col{
            width: 50%;
            height: 60%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .col_days{
            background: cyan;
        }

        .col_hours{
            background: magenta;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Высота в процентах должна задаваться относительно родителя.

```
    html,
    body,
    .timer-button{
      height: 100%;
    }
```

Флекс тут не поможет.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
 width: 400px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

html,
body,
.timer-button{
  height: 100%;
}

.timer-button {
    width: 90%;
    min-height: 50%;
  
    background: #e15d29;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

 .timer-button .title{
  background: lime;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
 }


  .col{
   width: 50%;
   height: 60%;
   overflow: hidden;
  }

  .col_days{
   background: cyan;
  }

  .col_hours{
   background: magenta;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="timer-button">
    <div class="title">Сегодня у нас</div>

    <div class="col col_days">
      <span class="value ng-binding">15</span>
      <span class="label">апреля</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col col_hours">
      <span class="value ng-binding">18</span>
      <span class="label">часов</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Если правильно понял суть проблемы то необходимо добавить:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

И к `.timer-button { height: 50%; }`